# Build Angular in production mode locally, in Visual Studio

Tags: angular, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I want to test the production version of my Angular app locally (i.e. serve from the `dist` folder), using Visual Studio (as part of a .net core app) && IIS Express - i.e. get the `F5` behaviour to serve the production version.

I thought this would be as easy as adding `--prod` to `start` (and/or `build`) but this doesn't work, from `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --live-reload false --prod",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "build:ssr": "ng run Website:server:dev",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
},
```

How do I get that to work correctly?

Comment: try this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server-spa. serving spa is a little bit more logic rather than just giving requested static

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite `F5`, but the closest I've got so far is to use a Powershell script:

```
cls

# build angular in prod to get compiled site (including service worker, etc) in dist folder
Set-Location -Path C:\Users\Sean\Desktop\ngsw\ngsw\ClientApp
ng build --prod

# iis params
$iisExpressExe = '"C:\Program Files\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe"'
$path = "C:\Users\Sean\Desktop\ngsw\ngsw\ClientApp\dist"
Write-host "Starting site on port: 8080"
$params = "/port:8080 /path:$path"
$command = "$iisExpressExe $params"

# open chrome in incognito to avoid cache 
[System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start("chrome.exe","--incognito http://localhost:8080/")

# start iis
cmd /c start cmd /k "$command"
Write-Host "Site started"

# sleep a long time...
Start-Sleep -m 1000
```